# Stop Double execution of events

Tags: javascript

So I have two text elements A and B, and on the onblur event of both objects I have the same validation function that will popup a message if B (a date field) is wrong.  Now, If I change A, and then select B, it will run the function twice.  it seems it runs it once for the onblur of both A and B.  This causes the user to get the same error message twice.

What do I need to do to force the onblur of A to not allow any other events to kicked off?

Here is an exmaple code i made up.  If you are on the 2nd field, and try to go to the first, if will run the function twice

```
function myVal(){
    if (document.getElementById("B").value == 'Z') {
        alert('Bad Value');
        document.getElementById("B").focus();
    }
}
```

---

```
<form>
    <input name="A" value="A" onblur="myVal();"/>
    <input name="B" value="Z" onblur="myVal();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You really need to post the code, or a simplified example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this solution:

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/SCsX2/

Another thing, this focus() thing is not desirable (at least that's how I feel). The red message should be enough:

***Better live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/SCsX2/2/

You can even run the validation code on each input-box keyup event. That will make the error message more responsive:

***Even better live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/SCsX2/3/

Comment: I really do like that first link.  its simple and clean and keeps them there till they have it right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function does not run twice, but by setting focus on the second field you force the user to stay there forever, or until he type correct value.. i.e. you have the user hostage.

Try to remove or comment the `.focus()` line and see if it's helping.

Comment: I just found this to be the issue in my testing.  Is there any way to force them to stay on the object till its properly populated without the validation running twice when thier wrong?

Comment: @Limey using jQuery and Šime Vidas code is one way, although personally I recommend running the validation only on form submit, and set focus only then.

Comment: The function does run twice.  You get the message twice anytime they try to leave it for another field that has the same validation.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same thing happen without the `alert()` call? `alert()` steals focus, causing whatever was previously focused to blur.

Comment: I will have to check, but i will need the alert to notify my users.

Just tried it wihtout the alert (i made a third text field where i add 1 to its value) and it still runs twice.

Comment: @Limey, can you use some other method to provide that feedback? Some kind of inline notification near the field?